# Plotting solution to system of differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I want to solve a system of differential equations:

```
OdeM = 1/2*σ*V1''[x] + ((a0*δ)/a1 - a1*x)*V1'[x] - 
    em*V1[x] == -((2*x - 2*ep*(a0 + a1*x)*λ)/(em - ep));
OdeP = 1/2*σ*V2''[x] + ((a0*δ)/a1 - a1*x)*V2'[x] - 
    ep*V2[x] == -((-2*x + 2*em*(a0 + a1*x)*λ)/(em - ep));
```

with the following boundary conditions:

```
Ic1 = em*V1[xhat] + ep*V2[xhat] == 0;
Ic2 = em*V1'[xhat] + ep*V2'[xhat] == 0;
Ic3 = V1[xhat] + V2[xhat] == (2*θ)/((ϵ - 1) (1 + φ))*xhat;
Ic4 = V1'[xhat] + V2'[xhat] == (2*θ)/((ϵ - 1) (1 + φ));
```

The general solution is given by:

```
SolGeneral = 
 DSolve[{OdeM, OdeP, Ic1, Ic2, Ic3, Ic4}, {V1[x], V2[x]}, x] // 
  Simplify

SolV1 = V1[x] /. SolGeneral[[1]]
SolV2 = V2[x] /. SolGeneral[[1]]
```

I parametrise the problem as follows:

```
δ = 1/100;
θ = 2;
ϵ = 3/2;
φ = 3/2;
ξ = 5/1000;
λ = 1/2;
σ = (1/5)^2;
μA = 3/20;
σA = 1/5;
rn = δ + μA - σA^2;
xhat = 0.05;
em = (δ*θ - Sqrt[δ^2*θ^2 + 4*θ*(ϵ - 1)*(1 + φ)])/(2*θ);
ep = (δ*θ + Sqrt[δ^2*θ^2 + 4*θ*(ϵ - 1)*(1 + φ)])/(2*θ);
a1 = (-δ*θ + Sqrt[δ^2*θ^2 + 4*θ*(ϵ - 1)*(1 + φ)])/(2*θ);
a0 = -((ξ + rn - 1/2*σ - σA*Sqrt[σ])/(δ + a1))*a1;
```

Then I want to plot the following functions:

```
SolJ1[x_] := em*SolV1 + ep*SolV2
SolJ2[x_] := SolV1 + SolV2
```

Mathematica returns errors related to an internal precision limit. How could I solve this?

```
Plot[SolJ1[x], {x, -0.2, xhat}]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SolV1 = V1[x] /. SolGeneral[[1,1]]` and `SolV2 = V2[x] /. SolGeneral[[1,2]]`?  Also, `SolGeneral[[1,1]]` has an integral expression with a Root object and when I remove just that component of the solution and try to integrate it directly, Mathematica returns it unevaluated.  I assume you're not looking for a numerical solution?

Comment: Yes a numerical solution works. But the solution is very long and I hope there is a more efficient way than replacing all the integrals with NIntegrate.

Comment: Regarding your other comment, I don't see any difference between [[1]] and [[1,1]]. Should there be one?

Comment: Ok.  I see that now.  No difference between [[1]] and [[1,1]] in that case.  Sorry.